# How to use <template> with dynamic IDs?

Tags: javascript, html, html-templates

Given a HTML-template like this:

```
<template id="paragraph-template">
<p>Hi, I am a paragraph</p>
</template>
```

I load and append this template via JS, like so:

```
let templateInstance = document.getElementById("paragraph-template");
myContainer.appendChild(templateInstance)
```

Now I'd like to add the template multiple times (i.e. in a for-loop) and I want the `<p>`-elements to each have a unique id, so the result would look like e.g.:

```
<div>
<p id="p1">Hi, I am a paragraph</p>
<p id="p2">Hi, I am a paragraph</p>
<p id="p3">Hi, I am a paragraph</p>
<div>
```

How can I achieve this with HTML-templates?

EDIT:
The example I provide here is minified – In the real world I have a template with many elements, which should all get a unique ID.

Comment: Copying the template element itself will break the "1 instance of an ID" rule. Can you explain *why* you're trying to do what you're trying to do, because there may be a much simpler way to achieve the final result.

Comment: @Archer my example just wasn't that extensive - itrw i'd just append the same postfix per cloned template to the existing unique id of each element – so that the cloned elements don't have the same id. So my question – in a way – was about not breaking the "1 instance of an ID" rule ;)

Comment: Then you should post something relevant to your use case, showing that you don't break other things. Applying an ID, and even ensuring it's unique, is simple, but we're not mind readers.

Comment: Ye… I admit my question wasn't as clear, as I thought – I tried to strip all unnecessary stuff, but should have left some essentials. I'll edit my question later (in a hurry now – probably would make things worse ^^) to reflect, what I realy meant (and what my solution to that was).
As Ehcnalbs answer solves the problem for the described case, I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you :

```
    let templateInstance = document.getElementById("paragraph-template");
    for(var i=1;i<4;i++){
        let clone = document.importNode(templateInstance .content, true);       
        clone.querySelector('p').id = "p"+i;
        myContainer.appendChild(clone); 
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this would work with the example I used here. Unfortunatly the template from my usecase contains manny elements, wich should all have a unique ID.
Is there a function to append a serial number to ALL elements IDs?
@Arindam Sarkar – upvote the answer then ;)

Comment: @kai-dj this work with any number element so what is the problem?

Comment: If I understand, in 1 content there are several element you need to put different id? May be you can use an external integer from the loop and increase for each id

Comment: @Supersharp I just suspected, there'd be more to `<template>` of course my problem would be solvable with this method, but it's a lot manual work ^^
…I chose a different approach now: a grails-controller wich takes a postfix, adds it to the id and returns the template.

Comment: @Ehcnalb I should have made my example more clear… itrw the elements already had a unique id, wich I wanted to expand with a serial postfix for each time I add the templates content, so the elements of one template-instance are linked and the ids'd differ from the other instances elements.